# Question about the history of the Internet

Tags: discussion

I recently listened to a podcast about the early beginnings of the Internet and I have some questions that I would like to ask. It is also technical in nature.

Is this the correct place to ask my question (history) or in which StackExchange do you suggest I ask my question?

Answer (score 4):

The History of Science and Math would probably love your question. Personally I wouldn't mind it here either. However, if there's a lot of technical content there's a good chance that's a better stack for it.

It kind of pains me to say that, because I practically lived most of the history of the Internet myself, have certainly tried to read up on the rest, and I don't hang out on that stack. However, I believe it to be true.

Comment: Alternatively, buy me a Negra Modelo sometime and I'll happily talk your ear off on that topic.